# Getting "This item is not reviewable" while reviewing close vote queue

Tags: bug, review-queues

I am just started for today to review the close vote queue, it was working as usual for first 10 questions then after when I was reviewing one question where system is saying "This item is not reviewable.". I am not sure what it means or it is bug.

### Confirm why it is so even that quesion still exist on site.

[Android app for fetching available seat info from a booking website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24467361/android-app-for-fetching-available-seat-info-from-a-booking-website)

Btw, I see one more interesting thing is that I closed that question as off-topic in close vote queue but why it is not showing in my "Close Vote" history but if you see the question then you will find first close vote on that is mine.

[image]

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195039/i-think-i-just-broke-review-audits and [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/187947/158100)

Comment: @rene but it was not audit with my case. Even it is not showing in my close vote history that is another bug.

Comment: Yeah, it might have something todo with two users being served the same task (so not an audit). And I couldn't find that question in the review history at all so it is a weird case. The team can only clear this up...

Comment: +1, I am also having some weird issues with the review queue. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261967/an-error-occurred-while-reviewing-this-item-please-try-again

Answer (score -2):

That basically just means that it was an audit.  Since audits are just for one specific user, it does not allow anyone to just visit the link.

You most likely refreshed the page after the audit came and now you see the error message.

Admittedly, it would appear to be a strange audit since it has a vote count of zero and is neither closed nor deleted.

You may also want to look at [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177382/non-reviewable-item) for other possible reasons.  But, it doesn't seem like any of those conditions apply because, like I said, it is not closed or deleted.

Comment: Ah, I am sure it was not audit because my close vote I can see on that question

Comment: I don't really understand why you being able to close the question means it is not an audit, but looking at it again, it does appear to be a rather strange audit: vote count at 0 and not closed or deleted.  Still, I've only ever seen this happen when it was an audit.