# After an error occured when submitting a review, it's impossible to continue

Tags: bug, review-queues

I do not seem to be able to proceed [with the review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/5180295) in any way as there seems to be no buttons available, not even skip. I have been waiting for a while now, so I believe it is just stuck.

The only option is to navigate away from this screen or close the tab. This had been preceeded by clicking on the "I am done" button in a previous review and then I had to wait a bit of time (10-30 seconds) to get this stuck screen loaded.

There seems to have been [some relevant discussion in the past](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211429/an-error-occurred-when-reviewing-this-item) which apparently got fixed. Is this bug coming up again? What is happening?

[image]

Comment: I've seen this error when I submit an edit from within my company's lan.  They have a filter for certain traffic over http.  Perhaps its on your end, not SO's.

Comment: @paqogomez: sorry, but I do not think you get the bugreport. The bugreport is not about the red box, but that it is not possible to continue. See the stuck "loading next item". Furthermore, there are 4254 reviews there, so definitely not a problem with the other end who may have had 1-2 seconds outage. SO ought to be able to continue with waiting without giving an error. That is another issue here, but that does not seem to be the main point based on the title.