# LQ Posts Review - Error while trying to delete vote after daily vote limit expiry

Tags: bug, status-completed, review-queues, low-quality-posts

**Background:** I had recently reached the trusted user level and as a result have expanded deletion privileges. I am also very active in Low Quality Posts review and exhaust my quota almost everyday.

Recently, I had noticed that everyday when I am reviewing the 15th or 16th item in the queue, I get an error message when I vote to "Delete" the post. The message is a very generic one and even though the bar says ***loading next item***, nothing actually happens once I hit this message.

**Review Item prior to clicking on Delete:**
[image]

**After clicking on Delete:**
[image]

When I refresh the page, I get the below screen which indicates that my vote wasn't actually cast and that I can no longer review that particular item. I am not too concerned about this because there are many other users who can complete the activity if required.

[image]

Note that the above screenshot is only the latest sample. In some previous cases, the post had only 1 or 2 "Recommend Deletion" votes when the error message appeared.

For the first few days, I wondered why this issue kept happening and if it was only me who was getting this error. But then I noticed that when I go back to Review homepage and return, the button changes from "Delete" to "Recommend Deletion" and so I guess the reason for the error could be that I have hit the delete vote limit for the day.

---

**My questions are:**

- If it was indeed because of me hitting the daily limit, shouldn't the button automatically change to "Recommend Deletion" without having to encounter this error?
- If the button name can't be changed automatically (for whatever reason), shouldn't the system atleast consider it as "Recommend Deletion"?
- Is this by-design? I tend to think of this as a bug because if it is not, it should atleast give me the same error message as in the below screenshot (taken from a question page).
  [image]

This error is definitely not a one off scenario as I can see it happening everyday since I reached the 20k reputation mark. I could not verify this in Meta (as there is no LQP review queue) or other SE sites (because I don't have near enough reputation).

I have already seen [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211429/an-error-occurred-when-reviewing-this-item) and [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261967/after-an-error-occured-when-submitting-a-review-its-impossible-to-continue) but my question is a bit different and hence I don't think it is a dupe.

Comment: Well, completely aside from your questions, there are two ways to waste your delete-votes: Deleting any own posts, and reviewing "Delete" in that queue, both before you spent all your delete-votes.

Comment: 20k problems are luxury problems.

Comment: Harry I have proposed a [feature request](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316010/stop-using-delete-votes-in-the-lqprq) to stop using the delete votes and just use recommend delete for everyone.  This would fix this bug as it would get rid of the situation.  I have linked to this as it is one of my selling points for the FR.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Not a problem. I did see your question a little while back and the proposal has my vote :)

Comment: the bug is still here: when reaching the max delete vote count, an error occurs, and when you reload "delete" becomes "recommend deletion". Happens everytime. Ok, it's a 20k+ user bug, we'll live with that :)

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for the report - this'll be fixed after the next build (*probably* Monday). I apologize for overlooking it for this many years! It's one of those edge-cases that somehow slipped through when adding additional checks at some point in the past.

Details of the problem and solution are on Meta SE: [My last Delete vote of the day used in Low Quality Posts queue always triggers an error and invalidates the review](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339240/my-last-delete-vote-of-the-day-used-in-low-quality-posts-queue-always-triggers-a/341940#341940)

Comment: So, essentially, the fix will give you an extra delete vote for the day in these edge cases?

Comment: Well, that's the funny bit, @Cody: in this scenario, *your vote still counted* - the post you voted on would still shuffle one more step toward deletion... You just didn't get credit for it in review.