# Stop using our delete votes in the LQPRQ when 20k-rep users recommend deletion

Tags: feature-request, status-review, review-queues, low-quality-posts, vote-to-delete

**EDIT:**

Now that the [testing has been completed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/344886/4342498) on [changing the number of reviews required to delete a post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342632/testing-testing-lets-test-the-low-quality-review-queue-for-science) I think this is even more needed.  We only need 4 reviews to delete a post so using 3 20K delete votes is only one less review than just having everyone recommend delete.

---

Currently, when a 20,000-rep user reviews in the Low Quality Post Review Queue (LQPRQ), we are charged with one of our normal "delete votes" when we recommend deletion. This differs from sub-20k users, who just "recommend deletion".

I would like to request that the LQPRQ stop using our 20k delete votes and just use "recommend deletion" for everyone, regardless of reputation level.

Referencing the data gathered on [How many 20kers use the LQRQ?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243247/how-many-20kers-use-the-lqrq) you can see that on all occasions (in the sample set) the 20K deletes on answers did not do any good as it still took 6 reviewers to delete the answer.

I know that, in theory, 20Kers should be able to clear out the queue faster as they only need three votes to the 6 recommend deletes but with so many more people in the [2K to 20K] range than 20K+ users in the queue, the 20K votes get drowned out by "recommend deletion" votes from sub-20k users.

Delete votes are a very limited resource with a maximum of 30 per day. I would like to be able to spend them on content that I find when using the site instead of using them up in the LQPRQ. I know I could use the queue after I spend my delete votes and I wouldn't have "wasted" them but to me it makes sense to just not use them in the queue.

This would also fix the [bug/issue where when you run out of delete votes while reviewing the answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300095/lq-posts-review-error-while-trying-to-delete-vote-after-daily-vote-limit-expir). When that happens your vote to delete does not get applied since you are out and you cannot recommend to delete as you still have a delete button. You have to refresh the page which then counts the review as completed even though you didn't actually do anything and you can only click next to go to another review.

Comment: If you opened the answer in a new tab are you still able to cast a delete from there separate from the VLQ review?  It would probably still be pointless as you point out, but is that the current behavior?

Comment: @ryanyuyu Yes that is the current behavior.

Comment: Related http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/230873/213575

Comment: What are "20K delete votes"?

Comment: @Trilarion When you reach 20K you can delete answers and closed question immediately if the are at -3 or below.  It basically expands the delete privs you get at 10K.

Comment: [20K - trusted user - Expanded editing, deletion and undeletion privileges](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user): Trusted users can vote to delete negatively scored answers. They can also immediately vote to delete closed questions at or below -3.

Comment: Related idea: [give me a separate pool of votes in the review queues](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285473/).

Comment: That's one reason why you shouldn't get to 20k! You get many complaints.

Comment: _"Delete votes are a very limited resource with only up to 30 per day."_ First world problems... I'm curious to see what percentage of users actually ran out of those votes at least _once_.

Comment: I'm confused; are you asking *users* to change their behavior? Or are you asking the devs to change the system in some way?

Comment: @TylerH I am asking for the devs to change the behavior of the queue.  Once you hit 20K it starts using delete votes.  I think it should not as there is no real benefit.  Especially now that only 4 reviews are needed instead of the previous 6.

Comment: @Cerbrus I do run out of votes frequently.

Comment: @NathanOliver Thanks, I've edited the post and title to clarify that for readers who don't know first-hand what exactly you're talking about

Answer (score 34):

I played around with the review interface a bit, and managed to come up with [a user script hack](https://gist.github.com/vyznev/58747ec3eb4a02bf19c2) to stop LQP "Delete" reviews from eating into the daily delete vote quota:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Stack Exchange LQP delete vote saver
// @namespace   https://github.com/vyznev/
// @description Tweaks the Stack Exchange Low Quality Posts review queue not to consume delete votes from 20k+ users
// @author      Ilmari Karonen
// @version     0.2
// @license     Public Domain (CC-Zero)
// @homepageURL http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/316092
// @match       *://*.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts*
// @match       *://*.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts*
// @match       *://*.superuser.com/review/low-quality-posts*
// @match       *://*.serverfault.com/review/low-quality-posts*
// @match       *://*.stackapps.com/review/low-quality-posts*
// @match       *://*.mathoverflow.net/review/low-quality-posts*
// @match       *://*.askubuntu.com/review/low-quality-posts*
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

var inject = function ($) {
    $( document ).ajaxComplete( function( event, xhr, settings ) {
        var m = /^\/posts\/popup\/delete\/(\d+)/.exec( settings.url );
        if ( !m ) return;
        var form = $('form#delete-question-form[action="/posts/' + m[1] + '/vote/10"]');
        form.attr( 'action', '/posts/' + m[1] + '/recommend-delete' );
        // show that it's doing something:
        form.find( 'input.popup-submit' ).val( function (i, txt) { return txt + ' :)' } );
    } );
};

var script = document.createElement( 'script' );
script.textContent = '(' + inject + ')(jQuery);';
document.body.appendChild( script );
```

Users with [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/fi/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/), [Tampermonkey](http://tampermonkey.net/) or some other compatible user script extensions installed can install this script by clicking [this link](https://gist.github.com/vyznev/58747ec3eb4a02bf19c2/raw/d0d7c1981ddbbb09678179e9f54f54644b5fd00b/se_delete_vote_saver.user.js).  By default, the script is active on all SE sites where you have deletion privileges; you can edit the `@match` lines to restrict it to only particular sites, such as only those where you regularly run out of delete votes.

Note that reviews made using this script still show up as "Delete" rather than "Recommend Deletion" in the review history, but since no actual deletion vote is cast, they won't eat into your daily delete vote quota.  (You can check this by comparing your remaining votes before and after a review.)

I did try to change the visible review type too, but it seems that trying to make a "Recommend Deletion" review while you still have delete votes left makes the review back-end fail hard — all you get is a red dialog box saying "An error occurred while reviewing this item."  Since there would otherwise be no directly visible indicator that this script was even doing anything, I made it add a smiley face to the submit button on any delete popups that it has successfully tweaked, like this → :).

Also note that, obviously, this script is messing around with the SE review interface in ways that are clearly not how it's designed to work.  While the script *seems* to work as intended for me, I make ***absolutely no guarantee*** that it will work for anybody else, that it will continue to work in the future, that it won't have some unintended side effects, or that it won't crash your browser, steal your car and burn down your house.  For all I know, SE might consider this code to be exploiting a security hole, and patch it ASAP.

(FWIW, if it *is* a hole, I consider it a rather benign one.  You need 20k+ rep to exploit it, and all it lets you do is save up your daily delete vote quota while reviewing low-quality posts — something that you could effectively do, slightly more awkwardly, just by delaying reviewing until the end of the day.)

Comment: Another US? :-( ... Can you add it to SOUP? (Atleast the dev version?)

Comment: @BhargavRao: I could, but I consider this to fall outside the scope of [SOUP](http://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch), since there could be users who might legitimately *not* want this. Maybe not *many* users, assuming that it indeed works as intended and has no unexpected side effects, but I'm still not quite ready to drop it in. SOUP is meant to be 100% uncontroversial, or as close as I can practically get to that.

Comment: Hmm, I get your point. Maybe the SO Devs need to first verify if this is *controversial*

Comment: I love this Idea but before I use it I would like to see what the SO staff has to say about it.  If they approve then at least we could use this in the interim.

Comment: Never trust a user interface.

Comment: Hack all UIs!​​