# Is triage question limit increased?

Tags: discussion, triage

Is triage questions limit increased as earlier while reviewing it was giving Thank you message after 20 questions, but today it gave that message after 40 questions.
Or is it related to reputations?

Comment: It's 20 unless there are more than 150 items in the queue. Then it goes up to 40. (The exact number is subject to change, it's not necessarily 150).

Comment: There is an [experiment going on](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342632/testing-testing-lets-test-the-low-quality-review-queue-for-science), might be related.