# A series of declined flags

Tags: discussion, declined-flags

That a flag gets denied from time to time is nothing new, but now I got three in a row, which seems a bit odd. I'm not sure if I was actually wrong to flag these, so I'd like to get a second opinion.

- [I have installed desktop GNOME in hdp2.5 ,but now i am not able access the hadoop services from docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42185580/i-have-installed-desktop-gnome-in-hdp2-5-but-now-i-am-not-able-access-the-hadoo)
- [UI thread ID in C# and restriction of it on single core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42199143/ui-thread-id-in-c-sharp-and-restriction-of-it-on-single-core)
- [Audio and video device test (ASP.NET MVC)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42199498/audio-and-video-device-test-asp-net-mvc)

**Note:** All three of them have been declined by a moderator:

[image: Declined Flags]

Description of the VLQ  flag:

> This question has severe formatting or content problems. This question is unlikely to be salvageable through editing, and might need to be removed.

Comment: You voted to close them as unclear. Why did you think you also needed to flag them?

Comment: I realize those are two separate things but don't they both apply? Isn't that the reason we *can* do both at the same time?

Comment: Related: [Am I misusing the “Very Low Quality” flag?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265764/)

Comment: @AzizShaikh Thanks for the link, I'm still not sure why those questions don't qualify as *"obvious, unarguable garbage"* (the part about unnecessary overhead makes sense). Opinions?

Comment: I can read the question and get a vague idea what is asked. How is that *obvious, unarguable garbage*? How would you qualify *hshsgsgyegdhd ^%%$#g hhh hreikrprld,dpri*((((* in that case? Ultra Low Quality? When the questions are edited by the OP they are salvageable.

Comment: @rene The official definition of the VLQ-Flag is *"This question has severe formatting or content problems. This question is unlikely to be salvageable through editing, and might need to be removed."* Doesn't that apply?

Comment: @rene I don't think that edits made by the author are included in the flag reason. Otherwise it wouldn't make any sense having that in there to begin with, since every question would be salvageable through edits made by the author.

Comment: @Seth Agreed. It is actually a big problem in *Triage*. A lot of question like these land in the *Help and Improvement* queue, probably because of that kind of reasoning.

Comment: Moderators have shown great reluctance in moderating content lately.  Not sure what is going on, smells like a directive from the company.  This started with the NAA flag, VLQ was next.  Ideally these flags are handled by the community but that is not happening, only 4% get reviewed within a hour by community members.  One mod even suggested that they should never see these flags, pretty bizarre.  Maybe it is time to start bypassing the official way, it is utterly incapable of getting rid of crap.  We'll get rid of these, maybe meta is the way to do this.

Comment: I know the definition, You ask me why a mod declined your flags. I explain why that is. All efforts on meta so far to change the meaning of VLQ has been either declined or didn't get enough support from CM and mod team. cc @Seth

Comment: @rene I see ... so basically it's kind of a lost cause? Best to accept things as they are and move on then. Thanks.

Comment: @rene We really need better flag reasons... Such a waste of time, we have multiple meta posts per day regarding declined flags, most of which could have been prevented simply by having clear flag reasons..

Comment: @HansPassant I've seen you make these kind of statements more often lately. I'm wondering though how you envision the practical implementation of engaging meta in getting rid of crap. Could you elaborate on that before I interpret your intentions wrongly.

Comment: @HansPassant I wouldn't call this reluctance, rather active resistance. If mods were reluctant they would just pass the post for community who would close and this would dismiss the flag as helpful. What they do instead is active involvement by declining the flag (seems like without even bothering to take a closer look at the question)

Comment: @HansPassant - I know it's fun to believe in conspiracy theories where Stack Exchange employees are telling moderators to do things that boost shareholder value, but that's not at all the case. In fact, the only guidance we've received from anyone at SE recently is to *not* handle "very low quality" or "not an answer" flags while [this experiment is ongoing](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342632/testing-testing-lets-test-the-low-quality-review-queue-for-science). Moderators disagreeing on how flags should be handled comes from our own personal judgment, not some SE orders.

Comment: Hmm, strange that mods are ignoring the SE guidance.  I'll avoid coming up with a conspiracy theory :)

Comment: Also, anecdotally, I think that experiment seems to be working well. I've seen a ton of obvious non-answers be deleted by the community before any moderator got to them, same with many low-quality posts. I think it's getting the review queues much closer to being able to handle these without moderator intervention. These flags were a few that slipped through the one-hour threshold, and the moderator flag queue has been low since the election, so it's hard to avoid handling the few flags left over. I really hope that experiment works well enough to let the community handle all of these.

Comment: I hope that this means you have some more time to also hit questions a bit harder

Comment: The flags we do have are better than no flags at all, which used to be the way it was.

Comment: At what point did we have no flags at all, @tiny?

Comment: Well, none of the flags we're always complaining about. We just had spam / offensive / custom (IIRC) at one point. Flags and review queues have been added, changed, and removed since. @Cody

Comment: Hmm yeah, a bit of historical research shows that when flags were first introduced in 2009, we only had spam, offensive/abusive/hate speech, and custom. The full complement of flags were introduced with the expansion of the flag system in 2011. Of course, I'm not sure that this is an improvement. The custom flag reason was all you really needed to get garbage removed immediately by a moderator, which is what the VLQ/NAA flags are supposed to be used for now. More importantly, though, a proliferation of garbage wasn't nearly the issue in 2009–11 that it is today.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

"Double-dipping" the process by flagging *and* close-voting doesn't have any benefit as far as I know. Both lead to the question being queued up for review, so using either one should suffice. Close-voting is obviously better, as flags (*other than "Spam" or "Rude/Abusive"*) cannot trigger something like automated deletion, as far as I know atleast.

---

Regarding the flagged questions: I would say that your flags were warranted, and should not have been declined. At most, if the moderator handling your flags felt **very strong** about it, they should've been disputed, but I can see no reason why one would choose to decline them.

As I've stated in my [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343630/a-series-of-declined-flags#comment446846_343630) already, I don't think that edits made by the original poster apply. Going by that understanding those questions are simply unsalvageable. We cannot know what the OP is asking for, atleast it question 1 and 3, and thus flagging those questions **is warranted** in my opinion.

---

That being said, I think the current flag reasons should be flagged as well. In my opinion most of them are confusing, and really don't do any good. As of now, I'd say that simply flagging a post **without giving a reason** would be more efficient.

The best option, in my opinion, would be new flag reasons. Clear borders, and clear instructions. Short, clear reasoning, the user quickly checks "Does it fit?", and the moderator quickly checks "Does it fit?", and the process is done.

That'd be much easier than applying those hella obfuscated reasons, especially considering that **every single one**, no matter if user, moderator or SE employee, **seems to have a slightly different interpretation** of the flag reasons.

Apparently though that has no priority, as most of the feature requests regarding flags didn't receive any attention (not even [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)).

Comment: Moderators can't dispute flags other than spam/abusive.

Comment: @Braiam Oh wow, I didn't know that. Why is that so? That sounds like a rather unnecessarily limiting "feature".

Comment: @Seth It's contrary to the point of the message.  The whole purpose of "disputed" is that it's there to mean something happened that prevented the flag from being able to be evaluated (usually the post being edited in the meantime, reviewers handling it, the post being deleted by the author, etc.).  When a mod actually evaluates a flag the idea is that it was helpful or it wasn't.  A mod manually disputing spam flags is really what the hack is, as that's just there because of how audits work.

Comment: Not understanding the reason a flag exists is not a reason to replace the flag with a different flag for what you wish you could use the existing flag for.

Comment: With the exception of spam and rude/abusive flags (which are special in other ways), there's no way for moderators to unilaterally "dispute" a flag save by going through review (and even then, it's not an option, merely a side-effect of how review works in some cases). The common meaning for "disputed" is simply, "there were different opinions as to how this should be handled", and traditionally it is reserved for cases where multiple reviewers disagreed with a flag. Last I checked, edits actually *validate* VLQ flags...

Comment: Personally, if something is flagged, it's because it needs moderator attention. Thus there's no need to vote to close it because a moderator is going to deal with the flag. So I vote for no double dipping. Either flag it, or VTC it.

Answer (score 1):

To add to servy's point in comments, a disputed flag by a mod would sounds like a 'skip' in review queue, if a mod doesn't agree he/she decline it and we granted them this power.
Asking about it on meta is OK in my opinion.

But, as far as I know, the mod will see the actual version of the post, not the one at time of flag, sometimes a flag doesn't apply anymore if the OP did act according to comments and did improve his question, it's still bad (take it as downvote worthy), but not anymore VLQ for the cases in questions. (With I didn't look at, answer from top of my head)

Personally I believe in mods to be fair on flag handling, but sometimes when you know the post history it's difficult to get in their shoes to understand their decision.