# How can a 4-year-old answer scoring 11 be flagged as VLQ?

Tags: support, flags, low-quality-posts

I recently came across [this answer](//stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/15226650) in review.

Though I reviewed it as Looks OK, I wouldn't necessarily mind if I'm wrong there.

The main problem is *how* exactly it was flagged. If I remember correctly, the "Very Low Quality" flag is disabled if the post is ~1 week old or has a score of 1 or more. This post is 4 *years* old and has a score of 11.

Are there exceptions to these rules? Are there other ways that posts can get into LQP?

Comment: Someone flagged it as VLQ perhaps because they thought it didn't answer the question.  Little do they realize, flags aren't the way to communicate, "I think this answer is wrong."  So saying that it looks OK if that's what you believe would be the correct action here.

Comment: It wasn't flagged as VLQ - it was flagged as NAA which has the same effect of putting it in that queue.

Comment: When I first read your title, I thought you were saying there was a toddler posting answers on SO.

Comment: @4castle: Looking at the quality of the average question nowadays, it wouldn't surprise me too much!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just so this can have an answer, I'll repeat what Jon said above: this wasn't flagged as "very low quality", it was flagged as "not an answer". That put it in the Low Quality Posts review queue.

As for why it was flagged this way, the person who flagged it doesn't seem to understand what "not an answer" flags are for.

Normally, this would have been declined by a moderator before you saw it in the queue, but we're holding off handling many of these due to [this experiment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342632/testing-testing-lets-test-the-low-quality-review-queue-for-science). The community will be seeing flags like this in review, along with the "not an answer" flags people use to mark answers they think are wrong, flags people use against competing answers, etc.