# How has review participation changed since the new topbar was added?

Tags: support, review-queues, top-bar, statistics

The new top bar design seems to coincide with more complaints that the edit review queue is full. Are there any numbers on pre- and post-new-topbar for reviews?

Comment: Perhaps this would be more appropriate as a comment over here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349118/is-the-top-bar-redesign-the-sole-cause-of-the-suggested-edit-slowdown , but the statistics I show there are over the last year. That's well before the top bar redesign. If I go back another year, the numbers carry back in roughly the same manner as the left of that graph.

Comment: @BradLarson mine is more general as I also ask about participation on all queues. The suggested edits queue is more "visible" due the hard cap, but the participation could have dropped across the board, which is concerning (if my fears come true).

Comment: I unfortunately don't have the same stats over time for other review queues, just suggested edits. That's also a more immediate problem because of the cap and the way it's blocking edits. Anecdotally, I'm seeing a lot more non-answers being deleted in Low Quality Posts review since [this change](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/344886/19679) and I don't have the sense that other review queues have fallen off. I think suggested edits might be a unique case, due to its previously prominent position on the top bar.

Comment: Maybe suggested edits are up? The close queue seems to be hovering around the same range as it usually would be.

Comment: @TinyGiant the cv queue number is kept down by aging away close votes, not sure we would see much difference.