# Handling of different flag types

Tags: discussion, flags

I frequently work in the first posts/late answers queues and flag posts if necessary. Most of the time it's 'not an answer' and seldom 'spam'. Both types of flags get handled (i.e. status changes from pending to helpful) quite quickly usually (seldom more than a few hours).

Now recently I flagged two posts as 'off topic' and 'primarily opinion-based' and noticed there is still no reaction on both of them; both are still 'pending' after two days and might soon 'age away'. Are these special cases handled differently, in different queues or does it need more people to decide or is it just because of the usual high load on many queues and my flags just got skipped because no one wants to decide? For me both cases seemed quite obvious, but I'm unsure if I'll use these flags again if they end up as aged away.

Comment: also related: [Testing, testing… Let's test the low quality review queue for science!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/344886/839601) -- this change is what causes VLQ and NAA flags to be handled quickly