# 2019: a year in moderation

Tags: discussion, moderation, statistics

It's New Year's Day in [Stack Exchange land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zulu_Time)...

A distinguishing characteristic of these sites is how they are moderated:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
> -- [A Theory of Moderation](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

While there certainly are [Moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) here, a significant amount of the *moderation* is done by ordinary people, using the privileges
they've earned by virtue of their contributions to the site. Each of you contributes a little bit of time and effort, and together you accomplish much.

As we enter a new year, let's pause and reflect, taking a moment to appreciate the work that we do here together.
And what could be more festive than a big pile of numbers?
So here is a breakdown of moderation actions performed on Stack Overflow over the past 12 months:

```
                  Action                  Moderators Community¹
----------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
Users suspended²                               1,340      1,615
Users destroyed³                               4,305          0
Users deleted                                  4,155          0
Users contacted                                4,475          0
User suspensions lifted early                     45          0
User review-bans lifted early                     64          0
User banned from review                        3,023      4,004
Tasks reviewed⁴: Triage queue                     34  1,239,611
Tasks reviewed⁴: Suggested Edit queue          2,940  1,141,695
Tasks reviewed⁴: Reopen Vote queue               223    185,719
Tasks reviewed⁴: Low Quality Posts queue         219    343,007
Tasks reviewed⁴: Late Answer queue                25    282,584
Tasks reviewed⁴: Helper queue                      9     31,119
Tasks reviewed⁴: First Post queue                 89    804,290
Tasks reviewed⁴: Close Votes queue             3,126    318,431
Tags merged                                      534          0
Tag synonyms proposed                            423        107
Tag synonyms created                             534         77
Tag highlight language set                        28          0
Revisions redacted                               490          0
Questions unprotected                              8         75
Questions reopened                             1,235      9,112
Questions protected                              141      6,039
Questions migrated                               418        758
Questions merged                                  94          0
Questions flagged⁵                             1,758    472,085
Questions closed                              33,862    306,210
Question flags handled⁵                       45,195    430,080
Posts unlocked                                   147        574
Posts undeleted                                3,325     70,345
Posts locked                                     432      8,517
Posts deleted⁶                               142,938  1,251,256
Posts bumped                                       0     34,352
Escalations to the Community Manager team      1,387          0
Comments undeleted                             1,770          0
Comments flagged                                 611    471,440
Comments deleted⁷                          6,075,670    981,980
Comment flags handled                        244,261    227,661
Bounties canceled                                227          0
Answers flagged                                3,707    366,618
Answer flags handled                         265,031    105,362
All comments on a post moved to chat           1,568          0
```

#### Footnotes

¹ "Community" here refers both to [the membership of Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators), and to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1).

² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

³ A "destroyed" user is deleted along with all that they had posted: questions, answers, comments. [Generally used as an expedient way of getting rid of spam.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88994/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deleted-user-and-a-destroyed-user)

⁴ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 2 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 2, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁵ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes).

⁶ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁷ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

#### Further reading:

- Wanna see how these numbers have changed over time? I posted a similar report here last year: [2018: a year in moderation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/378415/2018-a-year-in-moderation)...
- You can also check out [this report on other sites](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3A%222019%3A+a+year+in+moderation%22)
- Or peruse [detailed information on the number of questions closed and reopened across all sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/341507/2019-a-year-in-closing)
- For more information on who is deleting what, see: [What posts get deleted, and why?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296608/what-posts-get-deleted-and-why)

Wishing you all a happy new year...

Comment: Happy new year, @Shog

Comment: Comments deleted by moderators⁷ increased from 303,700 in 2018 to 6,075,670 in 2019! :o

Comment: 1.4 million deleted posts in one year seem like a lot (59,549,823 *posts* in more than 11 years and 18,720,517 *questions* in more than 11 years on Stack Overflow).

Comment: @Peter Indeed, let us never be called slackers again! ;-)

Comment: @WaiHaLee, it was because of a script to delete some of the useless old comments.

Comment: And that's *down* from last year, @peter... I'll post some details on that later in the week.

Comment: How many moderators quit?

Comment: @andrewtweber I believe the count of moderators who formally stepped down from Stack Overflow in 2019 is 5: Yvette Colomb, Robert Harvey, Ed Cottrell, George Stocker, and Jon Clements. Others have suspended their activity, but some of these have since returned to at least partial activity.

Comment: With so many mods gone, I wonder if next election will appoint many new mods.

Comment: Anyone loves stats? I've created a spreadsheet tracking the changes from past years as well https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1upnX9UX8ab8rde8DrGnOkZNnMqK0Qce0MgpLVTFUTUE/view?usp=sharing (discuss in [the Meta Room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197438/the-meta-room))

Comment: Can this be seen as an SEDE query?

Comment: @Zev No, a lot of this information is confidential and therefore not present in the data dumps that SEDE pulls from. You can, however, get some of the information from SEDE, though.

Comment: Who on earth needs to undelete comments? I can't imagine even a single situation.

Comment: @Boris mostly it's when there's a large amount of noisy comments on a post and it's easier for a moderator to purge *all comments* (which is a single action option for a mod) and then undelete comments that warrant remaining instead of individually deleting comments... (So if you've got 100 comments - it's easier to in one stroke delete 100 then undelete 2 than it is to go through and individually delete 98 comments...)

Comment: It's a curious decision to make a post about how it's not just the moderators who moderate soon after having conflict with a number of moderators.

Comment: @NotThatGuy: It might be a coincidence. As Freud once said, "sometimes a Jan 1 is just a Jan 1".

Comment: Moderators destroyed: too many

Comment: Perhaps if the community could action comments without needing moderator intervention, then there would be a lower prevalence for the type which get deleted. This would significantly lower the current load on moderators. If only there was an existing norm that every user was accustomed to for showing something isn't useful.

Comment: @JamesReinstateMonicaPolk I'm sure it wasn't intentional (in fact, that text was just a copy-paste from the post of the previous year), but if it were me I probably would've gone the other way and structured it like "while ordinary users do a significant amount of moderation, we also rely on elected moderators...". As it stands I can certainly see how someone might interpret this as saying that we don't need elected moderators all that much.

Comment: @Not That is very much intentional. A fundamental tenet of SE sites has always been that they are moderated by the community. Diamond moderators are exception handlers. Normal users handle most of the moderation/curation tasks, including voting, flagging, closing, etc. This is all covered in the "Theory of Moderation" blog post that is linked in the question. Shog's phrasing here is very much intentional, and has been used for *years* in year-end review posts like this. It has *nothing* whatsoever to do with recent events, including mods stepping down, and isn't an attempt to minimize them.

Comment: @CodyGray I only found last year's one and [one for 2016](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/340815/2016-a-year-in-moderation), which looked completely different. So the exact phrasing doesn't seem to have been around that long. I know it's community-moderated, I'm just making an observation about how someone might interpret this particular phrasing (and, given this, adding a bit more appreciation of elected mods may make sense, which doesn't even have to come at the cost of appreciating regular users).

Comment: I don't feel unappreciated, @Not, so I'm not sure what your point is.

Comment: @CodyGray Just because you don't feel unappreciated doesn't mean no-one does.

Comment: ["This, then, is the "community" who moderators are elected to represent: anyone who has ever participated constructively, anyone trusted to perform one of the countless small actions that - combined - account for the bulk of moderation performed on the site."](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284142/reduce-mod-election-vote-skewing-by-discouraging-passerby-users-from-voting/284144#284144) - read that if you want a long and thorough exploration of my opinions on moderators and moderation, @NotThatGuy; there's no way I can do justice to this topic in a couple sentences.

Comment: Could Andy perhaps weigh in on some metrics of his comment moderation automation?

Comment: 300k+ closed questions is a thing that should be improved.

Comment: It surely will be improved in 2020, @Vivek, since [the close threshold has been lowered from 5 votes to 3 votes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/391832/we-re-lowering-the-close-reopen-vote-threshold-from-5-to-3-for-good). I can confirm that this is definitely resulting in more questions getting closed more quickly, reducing the number of pending questions in the close vote review queue and decreasing the rate at which flagged questions are aging out of this review queue.

Comment: My concern is not closing question, but to make people ask better questions. I mainly answer in android tag and I see dozens of "I want " questions

Comment: Id like to have see questions asked and users created in that stat list.. @VivekMishra i see a lot of he SO I want you to either do it for me or others of please google it for me and weedle out what i need cos I didnts

Comment: @BugFinder unlike many of the information that Shog had in that table, those are public.

Comment: @VivekMishra unfortunately, that mission involves improving the askers too. You need to want to ask good questions before you can ask good questions. You need to educate yourself to a minimum base level to be able to ask good questions. You nee to want to search and research before asking to be able to ask good questions. Etc. etc.

Comment: OK, [26% of posts in 2019 ended up deleted (1.5 million)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296608/what-posts-get-deleted-and-why/296609#296609) (no answers (approx.) and by the mysterious "author vote").

Comment: @Shog9 Will there also be a post made for 'high-score/high-view questions' deleted by the community in 2019' for Meta to review/scrutinize?

Comment: How many moderators have been demoted? 1? For some reasons, all achievements and happy announcements recently taste stale.

Comment: I donno, @tyler - if y'all want it, sure

Comment: @Shog9 It seemed like a nice check against the deletion of questions. Optimize for pearls and all that.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica None were 'demoted' on Stack Overflow, but in the comments above you can see that 5 moderators stepped down of their own volition last year.

Comment: @TylerH Ah, that's true, this is meta SO.

Comment: Can we never un-feature this, in remembrance of the valued team member SO lost? @BhargavRao

Comment: Happy new year @Shog9

Comment: Update for @NotThatGuy: I now feel unappreciated :-(

Comment: @CodyGray Do you know what "Tag highlight language set" is?

Comment: It's possible to configure a default language for a tag, @user1271772 - this will be used for doing syntax highlighting on code blocks under questions with that tag if no block-specific language is specified.

Comment: The first link (link text *"Stack Exchange land"*) currently does not seem to render correctly (shown in bare source/Markdown form, `[Stack Exchange land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zulu_Time)`). Firefox 87.0 on Linux ([Ubuntu MATE 20.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_MATE#Releases) (Focal Fossa)). (Is it the HTML comment? A regression, a new bug, or something else?)

Comment: Looks to have been introduced during the Common mark migration, @Peter; different rules for embedded HTML

Answer (score 75):

It seems to me that the number of reviews (at least in specific review queues - [number graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKUIr.png), [percentage as of 2016 graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VueEc.png))

is dropping, while 3,000 more users were banned from review by moderators in 2019 than in 2018.

In addition, moderators have handled 45k flags *more* and the community *140k* less than in the previous year (2018). As a result, many NAAs have been left without being deleted ([related answer by Bhargav Rao](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/378422)).

Finally, there are about 500 unhandled [bugs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bug+review+-status-completed+-status-declined+-status-bydesign+-status-norepro+-status-review+-status-deferred+-status-planned+-status-reproduced) and [feature requests](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feature-request+review+-status-completed+-status-declined+-status-bydesign+-status-norepro+-status-review+-status-deferred+-status-planned+-status-reproduced) here, on MSO, and about 1k on MSE ([bugs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=closed%3Ano+is%3Aq+%5Bbug%5D+%5Breview%5D+-%5Bstatus-completed%5D+-%5Bstatus-declined%5D+-%5Bstatus-bydesign%5D+-%5Bstatus-norepro%5D+-%5Bstatus-review%5D+-%5Bstatus-deferred%5D+-%5Bstatus-planned%5D+-%5Bstatus-reproduced%5D), [feature requests](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=closed%3Ano+is%3Aq+%5Bfeature-request%5D+%5Breview%5D+-%5Bstatus-completed%5D+-%5Bstatus-declined%5D+-%5Bstatus-bydesign%5D+-%5Bstatus-norepro%5D+-%5Bstatus-review%5D+-%5Bstatus-deferred%5D+-%5Bstatus-planned%5D+-%5Bstatus-reproduced%5D)), a sign that review is completely neglected by SE employees. Zoe sums it up pretty well [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/385143) (although the answer is mainly about the CV queue): review tools need improvements and more reviewers are needed, **especially** in the CV queue<sup>1</sup>.

Please, please, invest some time in implementing feature requests and fixing bugs about review, making it an easier job for everyone.

Wish 2020 would be a better year in review than the others....

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>now dropped to 3.5k items, thanks to [this recent change](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/391832).</sub>

Comment: *“As a result, many NAAs have been left without being deleted.”* I don’t follow the logical leap here. Moderators didn’t do a sufficient job of cleaning up the site, despite handling 45k more flags? NAA flags don’t age away, so if they’re getting raised and not pending (no flags pending as of last night when we cleaned out the queue), then *someone* is handling them.

Comment: The "feature-requests" are handled in bulk by SE folks saying that [they no longer look at Meta for any feature requests](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/25/introducing-the-loop-a-foundation-in-listening/)... Someone needs to post "the feature request to end all feature requests" feature-request to request that all feature-requests no longer requested...

Comment: @Alexei Someone could just write a bot to cross-post feature requests from Meta on Twitter?

Comment: Honestly, all the drama last year, with the licensing, monica, and other things have dropped my motivation to invest really into reviews and reporting. I can't say I did much before, but I did every now drop in to review stuff, but right now I can't motivate myself. I think the thing that has changed for me is that, from my perspective, Stack Overflow  the company has changed into an uncaring cash hungry company, and I can't bring myself to care about increasing shareholder value without getting something in return. I used to believe SO cared about us, now I feel I am just a money making cow.

Comment: If SO were going to provide better tools for this, I think it's fair to say they'd have done so by now. The focus seems to be on turning the company into a cash cow at the moment - and that's really just about traffic, view counts, ad revenue, product revenue etc. at the expense of moderator tools, quality Q&A, and human touches such as swag for 100k members, etc.

Comment: @MichaelBerry I hear they've stopped handing out 100k swag now, so much for that human touch ;-)

Comment: @MichaelBerry "If SO were going to provide better tools for this, I think it's fair to say they'd have done so by now." That is not so clear. Over the last year, there definitely was company time spent on moderation tools -- mostly diamond, so sadly mostly invisible to the bulk of the community, but I'll take the 3 CV change -- and quality improvements -- with work on the ask questions page. Things are still being built. Who knows, maybe reviews will get some love this year, especially the audit systems. I sure hope they do.

Comment: @Tschallacka Isn't that the problem with democracies? When it goes wrong people loose motivation to participate. This makes the process become worse, etc.

Comment: @MichaelBerry are they no longer giving swag to 100k members?

Comment: @RuiBarradas-ReinstateMonic The thing is, I'm willing to work my ass off when I have the feeling I'm participating to the common good, for an organisation that works for the good of "all". Originally SO(in my view) was to make development knowledge available, common things findable, problems solvable. That got my passions up. But over the years SO changed from organisation to Company. With that change, my willingness to work for free for the company, that happens to have a community also declined.I don't care about companies, or working for free for them. Let them hire full time moderators.

Comment: @Tschallacka Same here. I am making up my mind these days how to continue ... but I am really not sure any more where and how my "investments" are going to happen here.

Comment: @cs95 They reasonably explained that ... problem is that "global" shipping is a complicated story. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/341231/replace-the-100k-and-250k-swag-instead-of-just-dropping-it for some other ideas ...

Comment: I'm talking from the future, 2020 has been a horrible year.

Answer (score 57):

How much has moderator activity *plummeted* in the last months?

Unfortunately, you only show numbers for all of 2019. But I have the strong impression that we'll see quite a dip in the end of 2019 in moderator activity, because of the Monica incident. Quite a batch of moderators appear to have suspended activity, or stepped down altogether. Or they were kicked out, of course.

And it does not look as if it is getting better in 2020...

Comment: I have only a small sample, but it seems that both very low quality posts (like serial code only answers and such) and outright rude comments fly under the radar these days.

Comment: Are you talking specifically about diamond moderator activity? Yes, it is true that several moderators resigned and others suspended their activity. No moderators were "kicked out" on Stack Overflow. The reduction in moderator strength unarguably had an effect. I don't have concrete stats that I can share, but I do know that the flag queue was not cleared as quickly. What that actually means is not clear. Moderator flags do not age away, and the queue has been cleaned out (down to 0) *multiple* times since the Monica incident, so it's not as if problems are falling through the cracks.

Comment: Having fewer active moderators simply means that it takes a bit longer for moderator flags to be handled. As of several weeks ago, one of our most prolific flag-handlers resumed his activity, meaning that the flag queue is essentially back to its normal clearance rate. Overall flag handling stats haven't really changed much either, I don't think, since flags have *always* been relatively slow to be cleared on Stack Overflow, given the site's massive volume. We're doing better now than we were at many points in the past ~10 years.

Comment: None of this is to justify the company's actions, of course, or to minimize in any way the statements made by a significant number of moderators stepping down. But this really isn't the appropriate place to make a statement about that, and you shouldn't read anything into the fact that this "answer" has not received an official reply.