# Good job, everyone!

Tags: discussion, moderation, community-moderation, community, appreciation

This is a thank you post to all the curators/moderators/custodians of this site, but also to the Stack Exchange Inc for creating such an amazing platform with such high standards of quality.

If you compare Stack Overflow with other Q/A site on the internet you can see a difference in the quality of content here. Often when searching information on the internet I encounter answers and comments poorly written, with typographical errors, unformatted code/error blocks, and sometimes even mojibake. I have to wade through noise, "me too"s, "thank you"s, and gibberish. One might consider it common courtesy, but for someone who has to search for information online on a daily basis, this is getting pretty annoying. I am looking for knowledge, and I do not need to see "Hi", "Thank you in advance", "Best regards" on every single post. This is why I am glad that content on Stack Overflow is curated by the community. All of us are doing a very good job at keeping the noise at bay.

The effects of our hard work moderating the content here might not be clearly visible, but let us not forget or diminish our importance. Without us putting in the extra work to edit the question into shape there would be less answers, less views, more garbage floating around, and consequently less helpful information available online. We do it not because we are getting paid, or because we want Stack Exchange Inc. to be more profitable, but because we want better technology, better and more secure software, and technological advancement. We invest free time into the community, because we know that the knowledge we share will be used to write better software, one which we will use either directly or indirectly. A lot of actions we perform on this site are not even rewarded in reputation points.

Take a look for example at review queues. Let's list out how much work has the community put into the reviews.

```
| Review queue         | reviews all-time |
|----------------------|------------------|
| Close votes          | 4,893,942        |
| Reopen votes         | 1,412,821        |
| Help and Improvement | 225,622          |
| Low Quality Posts    | 5,045,273        |
| Suggested Edits      | 11,592,526       |
| First Posts          | 6,153,659        |
| Late Answers         | 2,168,507        |
| Triage               | 9,282,666        |
```

That's more reviews than there are undeleted questions currently on Stack Overflow.

Not to mention all the edits, flagging, closing, deleting, and of course the work done by moderators. How often do you see spam or rude content? Even if bad content is found, you can be sure that if you flag it, your flag will be handled promptly by either one of the moderators or by the queues. Obviously, I do not have the data on how many flags are being raised every day, how many deleted posts are there or how much work is done behind the curtains by our dear moderators. I am only able to say how many deleted answers I see, since I reached 10k reputation points. It surprises me how many threads have more deleted "answers" than undeleted ones.

We have dedicated chat rooms for coordinating the user-level moderation work (SOCVR, SOBotics, Charcoal). We have multiple bots (SmokeDetector, Natty, Queen, Guttenberg, Fox9000), which identify bad content and either flag it automatically or consolidate this information for users to take an action. We go above and beyond to care for the precious knowledge we have put on this site. There were days when I ran out of post flags, comment flags, close votes, delete votes, and up/down votes. We want the gold to shine and we throw away the pyrite.

Of course the quality of the content on this site would not be possible to be what it is now if the product itself wouldn't allow us to moderate the posts. We are thankful for all the tools, which let us monitor and improve the posts. We would like to have more powerful tools, but even with what we have today it is possible to guard the site's high standards.

So, thank you! Keep on doing what you're doing. [Good work, everyone!](https://getyarn.io/yarn-clip/22e1df99-d086-4498-b5e2-94c628dad0e2)

Comment: The sentiment is understandable, but I can't help but feel like this is almost all fluff. Well documented, but fluff.

Comment: @BoogaRoo Sometimes fluff feels good.

Comment: Yeah, I know exactly what you mean. I really hate having to weed through the noise and the “thank you”s and...wait.

Comment: Yeah, everything is about feelings these days. Ironically, this question is representative of how much the hard work we achieved back then may possibly allow the renewed community to focus on feelings. You know, back then, when the onus was on getting things done instead of passing time playing victims. How I miss these times...

Comment: When I saw the question title in the Home Page queue I dared to think it was a post from a staff member/director ... ah, well. Good stuff, anyways.

Comment: Hey, it's the real people who take time to give you a pat on the back when things are rough, eh @adrian?

Comment: @Shog9 it's nice to see you around, don't go anywhere ^__^

Comment: Lots of info on flags is available in [2019: a year in moderation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392550/1364007).

Comment: @waihalee only one year, but there's no total.

Comment: Ok, my comment was deleted, why? I'm genuinely asking what this is a parody of, or what the purpose of this post is. I've seen that table elsewhere.

Comment: @CodeCaster No it's not a parody, but if you have some accusations then it would be nice if you provided a link yourself. This is a genuine post based on my own feelings and I never meant to sound satirical.

Comment: I don't have a link, because I don't know the answer to the question I'm asking you. So I asked something to clarify the question, and my comment got removed. Figures.

Comment: It didn’t strike me as a constructive line of discussion overall, @CodeCaster. More importantly, Dharman had already replied telling you that your assumption was incorrect and this was genuine. Thus, in order to keep the comments clean and focused, I removed that whole tangent.

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​9 million on Triage? That's about a half of all the questions asked on SO!