# How many times do questions go through a delete/undelete cycle by the same group of users?

Tags: discussion, support, statistics, vote-to-delete

A moderator of the site [is proposing a new rule](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/407860/792066) to limit the number of delete and undelete votes to one per user per post. Given that much discussion is happening there and the rhetoric is high, I want to ask "is this such a widespread issue that would need this?"

Since Stack Exchange is pushing for a data-driven development, I believe this would help enrich the discussion, for the last 365 days:

- How many questions have been voted to delete more than once and been deleted by the same user?
- How many questions have been voted to undelete more than once and been undeleted by the same user?
- How many cycles of deletion-undeletion does the same user participate in deletion?
- How many cycles of deletion-undeletion does the same user participate in undeletion?
- How many cycles of deletion-undeletion do the same list of users participate in deletion?
- How many cycles of deletion-undeletion do the same list of users participate in undeletion?
- How many users participate in cycles of deletion-undeletion?

Some information can be gleaned from [SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/data-explorer/info), but this would be skewed towards posts that end up undeleted, so rather than having incomplete data, I prefer a complete data set.

If someone has a proposal of information that could help us to take decisions, feel free to post it.

**Bonus points:** the same but for close votes where applicable.

Comment: Don't forget to include total (un)deleted question so we can see how remarkably small the impact is these (un)deletionists have.

Comment: @rene I think this fam got you https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/404558/792066

Comment: Posthistory has rows with typeid 12 and 13 which have a Json in the text field that holds all voters. You can only get data for currently undeleted questions. For a complete set you need a CM to run the query on the internal SEDE.

Comment: @rene will you write the query so they can run it?

Comment: The bigger question is, "Do most of those posts *deserve* to be deleted?"

Comment: @jpmc26 are you aware that last year alone 1.5 million post where deleted? There were just shy 3 millions questions asked.

Comment: Half of all questions deserving deletion sounds entirely reasonable to me.

Comment: @jpmc26 Pareto would like to disagree.

Comment: don't forget deletions due to roomba. those are as well in that 50%.

Comment: "...such a widespread issue that would need this..." Just a comment: It doesn't need to be a widespread issue to need something. Even if it occurs only rarely (let's say once per day) it might bother people. For example: moderators are fired by the company only once in a decade (it looks like) but still there is a huge procedure now what to do in that case. There is no real reason to let delete/undelete wars go on forever until one group of users simply give up (and go away). Better to use the successful recipe from close/reopen votes wherever possible. Having said that, I love statistics.

Comment: @Trilarion something that affects everyone on the site, needs to be actually worth it.

Comment: @Braiam Doesn't the change only effect users with VTD privileges? So only [278 / 399212](https://stackoverflow.com/users?page=278&tab=reputation&filter=all) ~= 0.07% of all SO users. And I'm doubtful 100% of users with 20k go on VTD VTRO wars. Where did you get "everyone on the site" from?

Comment: @Peilonrayz if every user of those get the privilege they will be affected. Rules that are pushed just because they negatively a small group, reeks to discrimination. (Same argument would happen the other way)

Comment: I was gonna answer, but this is really more of a comment; I agree with @Trilarion. This data certainly wouldn't be *un*helpful, but knowing how often delWars occur doesn't tell us much about whether this is a good change if we don't *also* know how helpful the tool we're losing is. You seem to presume that losing multi-delete privilege isn't worth it– but we don't have *any* data that says it's even used in a helpful capacity. *That's* the data that would be helpful here: "How often are multi-deletes used 'peacefully'?" We need to know how useful this tool is to gauge whether it's ok to lose.

Comment: [Source](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/404558) for the 1.6 million deleted questions in 2020 (near "Posts deleted" - add the two numbers). [2019 edition](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392550) (1.4 million).

Comment: I agree with zcoop, I think the important data to see is, out of all the questions that get undeleted by users, how many should have been undeleted, and how many go on to be deleted again?

Comment: This is all very interesting, but all you really have to ask is this: why should a user have the ability to delete vote (or undelete vote) the same question twice?  It's not like this concept isn't proven; we already do it with close votes, and have done so for years.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I would argue that the solution for close votes was also flawed. We still have close-reopen cycles. It didn't stop either side of the argument. The only thing it accomplishes is that it requires more users to be involved.

Comment: The idea of "one bite at the apple" was never meant to *eliminate* close/reopen cycles; it was meant to *reduce* them, which it does very well.

Comment: @RobertHarvey do you remember the post that introduced the one vote per post? [I didn't get the reference all those years back](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/348596/792066) about when it was introduced (nor I found the one that upped the number from 3 to 5 either).

Comment: "Since [SE] is pushing for a data-driven development" This isn't something that involves development, rather just deciding whether to enforce a (new) rule, so I don't see the relevance.

Comment: @404 the rule is interim to implementing it on the system. I prefer that there's data in hand rather than the recent Twitter Driven Development.

Answer (score 22):

It is stupidly low. It is so low that more users have viewed, voted, commented and answered on the Meta posts than the total number of posts or users involved in these (un)delete "wars". And I didn't even bother to exclude the moderators ...

Let me answer this bullet (all numbers based on currently visible posts. I dare you to challenge me that the stats would skew a lot when deleted posts are taken into account):

> How many users participate in cycles of deletion-undeletion?

Based on [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1413477) I conclude:

- 62 users have deleted the same posts more than once (result set 1)
- 57 users have undeleted the same posts more than once (result set 2)

I'm not going to create the queries for your other bullets as we can eyeball the outcome here. If you insist you can ask a CM to run my query on the internal SEDE instance but that would only be to counter that one user that dares to claim these numbers are fake.

Comment: [You didn't resist, huh.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/407898/how-many-times-do-questions-go-through-a-delete-undelete-cycle-by-the-same-group/407963#comment845044_407898)

Comment: This is very good news indeed. This means that it's certainly feasible for mods to manually handle these users, which is a concern that has been brought up on the related proposal. If it were many users who occasionally delete/undelete multiple times, then it would be harder to solve without automation. But since it's just a few users who're responsible for a majority of the issues, this should be quite easy to handle manually.

Comment: @cigien I think the rule is only created so mods have something to refer to when they handle these cases. Up till now users could easily get away with: *It is not forbidden, don't make up your own rules*. We can't have nice things.

Comment: "I dare you to challenge me that the stats would skew a lot when deleted posts are taken in to account" Not sure if this is a daring contest, but of course it changes and nobody knows how. Probably a doubling but maybe less or more.

Comment: Yes, that seems to be exactly why the rule is introduced. A good thing in my opinion; allowing multiple delete/undelete seems to be an oversight, and if mods are needed to handle it, as opposed to fixing the system (or until the system is fixed), that's fine.