# Request for clarification on moderation policy regarding deletion of posts under Meta discussion

Tags: discussion, meta, moderation, vote-to-delete

[The following comment was posted on a Stack Overflow question:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67873954/why-is-only-the-first-case-statement-applied-in-a-google-data-studio#comment119985817_67873954)

> Moderator Note: We will not be deleting questions while they are under active discussion on Meta. Please note that having participated in the deletion of this question within the next 48 hours will likely result in the suspension of your account. –
> Cody Gray♦ Jun 8 at 7:16

This then resulted in a Meta question asking whether that comment is/should be/will become official moderation policy: [Should posts that are actively being discussed on Meta be temporarily exempt from deletion?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408248/should-posts-that-are-actively-being-discussed-on-meta-be-temporarily-exempt-fro)

The above Meta question **did not result in any concrete policy decisions** as far as I can see. However, the user who asked that Meta question has now posted [the following comment on Stack Overflow questions under discussion on Meta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59922901/how-would-i-increase-the-max-build-limit-in-minecraft#comment122065848_59922901):

> Please note that questions being discussed on meta are not eligible for deletion for up to 48 hours. All other actions are fine, but please refrain from casting delete votes during this period. – cigien 13 hours ago

I have two issues with this:

1. As stated, the claimed policy is not, **as far as I'm aware**, official moderation policy regarding **all** Stack Overflow questions being discussed on Meta.
2. As such, the user in question - who is not a moderator - is **misrepresenting Stack Overflow moderation policy**.

I thereby request a clarification from the **official moderation team** on whether the statement made by Cody Gray is now **official moderation policy** on all Stack Overflow questions being discussed on Meta.

Comment: I flagged (very recently) that comment for deletion saying _"Considering the age of the meta discussion, this comment makes currently no sense here and it's currently noise. If anything, this should be posted as its own meta post."_. I think that this question _could_ fit the bill, if not focusing too much on individual users. Let's just clarify the consensus and policy, no need to get all belligerent about this.

Comment: If I don't name names, how will the people involved know that they should be reading this question? About the only direct user-to-user comms on the platform is chat and in my experience most people ignore it if unsolicited.

Comment: "Naming names" does not inform anyone about being mentioned. And meta is certainly not meant for "direct user-to-user comms". Asking for clarification about rules is very fine, you needed very little else besides quoting the original comment.

Comment: @Cody's comment is correct according to official polices and most users' desires/needs. However, it only takes 3 people to delete the question, and I am not aware of a single instance where a delete voter has been suspended for breaking this policy, so it's never enforced.

Comment: @user000001 how would you expect to become aware of delete voter suspension? Such things are not discussed publically so are you monitoring all 10K users accounts, checking whether they fall to 1 rep and then somehow asking them?

Comment: If a policy is never enforced, is it still a policy? Should it still be a policy?

Comment: A glance over the linked question makes it rather seem like support for that kind of policy was meager at best...

Comment: @yivi Such a declaration is unlikely to be made on that question due to its age. Further, there is now a possibility of incurring a very severe penalty (account suspension) for performing a very normal action (casting a delete vote). Finally, since some users are now interpreting what may or may not be official moderation policy as official moderation policy, it is of paramount importance to get clarity from the moderators as a whole to prevent further confusion and/or disinformation.

Comment: Imagine scenario... someone casts delete vote on a question. Someone else starts discussion on the Meta about that question. Someone else sees question in recently casted delete votes in Tools and agrees with delete vote, not knowing about Meta discussion (if there is a long thread of comments, even having one pointing to Meta discussion does not guarantee it will be read). Insta suspension. I really wouldn't like that.

Comment: I believe this refers to "delete/undelete" wars, which in turn triggered some recent change so that one user can only cast one delete vote per post. Also I think there's a big difference between 1) casting repeated delete votes "in war" with some other user (I'd expect moderators to take action), 2) finding some discussion on meta then go to the discussed post and cast a delete vote before consensus (questionable, but then those trusted with delete votes should be able to use them no matter context), and 3) coming across some random post while browsing/reviewing and casting a delete (fine).

Comment: Ref for @Lundin's comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/407953/why-am-i-not-allowed-to-vote-to-delete-or-undelete-another-users-post-more-than

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar Except.. there's a comment on the post that it's being discussed on meta, so it's not a secret even on the post itself.

Comment: If this policy is enforced without an announcing comment on the post itself, it should ideally be made clear in the delete guidance, to avoid people that aren't meta regulars stumbling upon a bad post that happens to be discussed on meta, casting a delete vote and suddenly getting themselves suspended.

Comment: Frankly, I would love to see it explicitly stated as such and, what's more, adopted as endorsed policy. I am also a proponent of a *complete* lock for 48 hours except for maybe commenting/closure (to prevent inability to request clarifications updates and prevent benefiting FGITW answers). At least then we can stop band aiding each other with references to "what's Meta effect" (this goes both ways - it's just as disheartening to see lackluster posts get double-digit scores due to good behaviour as it is seeing good posts going down for bad behaviour of the OP)

Comment: @Scratte I mentioned that... existence of the comment does not mean you will actually read it, especially if it is not the only one. You can decide that something is delete worthy without reading the comments.

Comment: I see two big problems with this policy, if it is indeed one: 1) It is an extremely severe punishment (suspension) for a completely normal action (casting a delete vote). The only way to prevent this, is to do a thorough search of [meta] each and every time you cast a delete vote. 2) Any user who wants to keep their crappy question from being deleted can now just post a meta question about their question, thus preventing anyone from casting a delete vote, otherwise they will be suspended.

Comment: Perhaps no one has been suspended until now (it might be too extreme to suspend someone just for a single delete vote, not for repeated cases), but we never know if anyone gets a moderator message instead.

Comment: Yea, suspension seems... excessive. __Especially__ if this isn't official policy. And if this _were_ official policy, there should be systems in place to prevent the vote from being cast, or a _proper_ banner should be added to the question, instead of a simple comment.

Comment: @JörgWMittag re: 2) it depends. If someone is really interested in improving their question, then I don't see why it should be deleted instead. But there should also be *a time limit* for the asker to take real actions to really improve it. Otherwise, use Roomba as the super delete-vote.

Comment: Keeping posts under discussion from being deleted is a fine idea. But, suspension is excessive for what could well be an innocent mistake. Only if it happens over and over again, and the users fail to respond to warnings, does suspension make sense IMO - just like every other rule.

Comment: @AndrewT. AFAIK, authors can edit and vote to undelete their question if they wish to do so (unless deleted by community, but everything is weird when community is involved).

Comment: @JörgWMittag "Any user who wants to keep their crappy question from being deleted can now just post a meta question..." In practice doesn't happen very often if at all. People just post their content and then move on in almost all cases.

Comment: @Trilarion In practice, this would be an almost brand new policy, so we don't know if the existence of such a policy would increase Meta interaction significantly once it becomes more widely known. Besides that, if a mere [60-some-odd cases all time is enough to justify a rule](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/407963/1394393), then who cares how infrequent the abuse is? Heck, if Meta interaction is that rare, why do we care so much about deleting questions under discussion?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The TL;DR here is it's not a **formal** policy. We try to craft formal policy with Meta and [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) for maximum discussion and feedback ([like this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/407860/rule-proposal-one-delete-undelete-per-post) and [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/407953/why-am-i-not-allowed-to-vote-to-delete-or-undelete-another-users-post-more-than)).

I haven't talked to Cody but I think [Makoto is correct here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/408249/2370483)

> Ultimately, the moderators can do what they like/say what they like in this regard. They're the ones that deal with the flags about this kind of question anyway, and I'm reading Cody's remark here more as him putting his foot down as opposed to now saying in a blanket fashion that "all questions being discussed on Meta are exempt from deletion".

There's a frustration (especially among mods) that Meta effect deletion is sometimes too quick to allow discussion. I mean, if you delete it, anyone under 10k can't weigh in (unless some kind soul comes in and screenshots the thing, which is then unwieldy to read). It is **preferable** that you not delete things under Meta discussion (and to that end, a comment like "This post is [under discussion on Meta](/help)" is useful).

I have deleted cigien's comment making this sound like a formal policy. We would *prefer* you to not delete it until some time has passed, but there's no rule to stop you from doing so.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Does that mean we're also no longer going to see threats of _suspension_ in this context? That seems quite excessive for cases where someone might not even have seen the _preference_ not to act on something.

Comment: @Cerbrus if a mod feels strongly enough to babysit **one** question and demand it not be deleted (which is how I read Cody's initial comment that started all this), that's their prerogative. I have, on occasion, tossed my diamond around to threaten folks not to take a certain action without some sort of Meta discussion, but it only applied in that one context.

Comment: Of course I'm generalizing here, but that seems like an easy way to create a shitstorm... It's quite a strong message to send when the question (looking at the timeline) probably only has a few delete votes. But that's just my $0.02

Comment: I'm personally not in favor of this decision (obviously), but *some* ruling is vastly better than none, so thanks a lot for the clarification. My comment implying that a formal policy is in place was intentional, in the hope that it would spur an official ruling, and in that regard, I'm pleasantly surprised how well that worked out :) Of course, I won't leave such a comment again (especially now that it's official), and I'll frame it purely as a request to refrain from deletion.

Comment: As someone that has had 10k on other sites but not this particular one, I don't find screenshots particularly limiting. I do find frustrating however, that I can't moderate a post as I see it fit if I can do it.

Comment: It should be noted that it's not just moderators that engage in this kind of overly fastidious approach to curating the questions that are asked.  I'm not on here enough to be in the 10k club, but I have this understanding that much of the "curation" can occur quite arbitrarily without any kind of moderator attention at all and I know there aren't many official moderators, but there's an endless list of people ready to cut questions from the site over interpretations of policies that are based in opinion that haven't been elected to be an official moderator.

Comment: @user56983 we are here for a library of high quality questions unique to software development, all those "arbitrary rules" where created to approach that goal. If you see someone applying the rules ignoring the spirit of them, please, show examples so that the rule can be clarified.

Comment: @user56983 well if you insist; I think that’s an awfully pessimistic interpretation of how SO works.

Comment: @user56983 The beauty of Stack Exchange is that if you have a demonstrable example of poor curation by non-moderators on Stack Overflow, you can start a discussion **right here on Meta** to get it sorted out. The fact that you haven't done so is telling, as is your profile page rant.

Comment: "We would prefer you to not delete it..." We should then rephrase the comment by cigien slightly: "Please note that questions being discussed on meta are preferably not for deletion for up to 48 hours. All other actions are fine, but please refrain from casting delete votes during this period."

Comment: @Trilarion [As pointed out in the linked discussion about this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/408303/70345), there already exists a mechanism for mods to prevent deletion: question lock. I don't see why they can't just use the existing tools that serve this purpose instead of making heavy-handed threats of suspension. **If it's official policy it should be enforceable by the system**, and locks fall into that category.

Comment: But it's not official policy, @IanKemp. It's just a preference.

Comment: @Cerbrus Yeah, poor choice of words. My point still stands: whether it's a preference or official policy, the system already allows for enforcement, so the threats are unnecessary.

Comment: @Braiam Two cases I can think of in which a screenshot can be limiting are: if you're in a location with little available bandwidth (or very expensive) so you would rather load text than a screenshot that is probably heavier; the other situation is if you are visually impaired and there's no alt text to the screenshot for the narrator tool to read (even then, it doesn't beat having the actual post I think).

Comment: @IanKemp "If it's official policy it should be enforceable by the system..." And if it's not enforceable by the system it shouldn't be official policy? Also official policy sounds a bit strange. Are there unofficial policies too? But I thought about it and I would prefer if the mods would simply deletion lock questions that are discussed on meta. That's by far the easiest way to obtain the preferred behavior.

Comment: @Trilarion "if it's not enforceable by the system it shouldn't be official policy?" Yes. That is the whole point of having a software system, so that policies can be defined and enforced without human interaction. A software system that requires humans to arbitrarily enforce policies is ripe for abuse, discontent, and failure. Which is exactly what's been happening to Stack Overflow for the past decade, coincidentally.

Comment: @Clockwork if that was the case then if the question itself had some image, those limiting factors would apply too. Note here, that someone tries to summarize the content of the question in text form anyways when arguing one way or another on the content, so those that the screenshot isn't accessible due other reasons are still informed.

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, you're saying that a moderator should evaluate a question and determine whether it's controversial enough to warrant discussion or not. (The other interpretation is that it depends on the moderator's feelings about *policy* regarding this issue, and inconsistent moderator behavior sounds like a bad thing.) That would only *strengthen* the case for using locks as the normal procedure for borderline cases where discussion makes sense, since a moderator already needs to view the question and make an evaluation anyway. Then they don't need to babysit it, either.

Comment: Also, if Cody did not mean to make a blanket statement about policy, his choice of words was *extremely* poor. "We will not be deleting questions while they are under active discussion on Meta," **is** a blanket statement, intentionally or not. You should discuss his intentions with him before making such an assertion about what clearly reads as a general statement applying to many cases.

Comment: @jpmc26 100% agreed on both points, and they're partially the reason why I asked this question (although I didn't mention them as my primary concern was getting the mixed messaging sorted out ASAP). It seems like is that the left moderator hand is not talking to the right moderator hand, which has resulted in different users going by what different hands are saying, and it's all yet another unnecessary mess that could have easily been avoided by just communicating properly. The fact that Cody themself hasn't posted here is also concerning.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't really see what is "concerning" about it, @Ian. If you'd like to hire me full-time to moderate, let me know; I can send you my address to mail the checks. Otherwise, I have to keep working this real-world job, and that is leaving me with absolutely no time at the moment to do any moderation work, much less read and reply coherently to Meta threads. I think Machavity's interpretation is perfectly apt. I've always had little inclination to establish "policies"; I'd rather apply common sense. Deleting something out from under a discussion is *not* in keeping with common sense.

Comment: Regarding the "suspension" tangent: as I'm certain I've expressed elsewhere on Meta, the unfortunate reality is that moderators don't have any real tools to prevent a user from exercising certain privileges (and especially not in a particular context) other than suspension. Thus, if a particular user is repeatedly casting votes to delete a post (which they would normally have privileges to do, but should *not* be doing, because they were explicitly asked *not to do so* by a moderator), then moderators don't have any recourse to stop this behavior aside from suspending the user.

Comment: Cody... I'm concerned because I want to hear your side of the story, not because I believe or wish to imply any sinister intentions by you or other mods. I'm concerned because you not participating in such a discussion is unusual, and it made me wonder if something is going on behind the scenes with the mod team, and/or with yourself. And now you've clarified what's going on, and I understand, and thus I'm no longer concerned. Thanks for letting us know, and I hope you get your time back soon, whether that is to moderate SO or do other things you want.

Comment: @CodyGray Think there's some context misunderstanding. This post isn't about repeat delete votes. It's about a blanket ban on deleting questions under Meta discussion. Which you do have a tool to prevent: locking.

Comment: @jpmc26 I can't really offer links to source, but I'm pretty sure I remember the "you can lock" argument being thrown around this topic, and being more or less dissipated because locking the post prevents any kind of interaction with it, which firmly puts that in the **non-solution** field. Locking the post is not an appropriate solution to the problem of fast delete votes on discussed posts because it prevents all kinds of interactions with a post.

Comment: @FélixAdriyelGagnon-Grenier which I respond, then what's the point? If you don't like a particular interaction with a post, would you say you don't want people downvoting a post? Upvoting a post? Editing a post? I prefer that whatever solution is an all or none. Either people should be able to interact with a post, or they should not. If moderators are not happy with that, well, nobody gets what they want.

Comment: @FélixAdriyelGagnon-Grenier Ian linked my answer above. I still reject that reasoning. The entire argument here is that the Meta effect around deleting needs to be hindered so people can discuss the post more easily. If you're trying to limit the Meta effect, you should just go all the way: prevent downvote pile on, prevent pity upvotes, prevent Meta effect close/reopening. The only real downside of a lock is that it prevents editing, and frankly, maybe that's not so bad, either, since the type of edits required should be part of the discussion anyway. Major edits are extremely rare anyway.

Comment: @IanKemp My honest experience has been that the more effort I put into a question the more actively people will vote it down and then on the other hand that the less effort I show, the more likely I am to get an answer, when really, I'm not satisfied with the question.  Getting a question closed and deleted is one thing, but getting banned from asking questions all together over a complaint about a duplicate is heavy handed and unnecessary, especially when there's a good reason that said question is not a duplicate, whatever that question was.