# "This item is no longer reviewable" on an ended review

Tags: support, review-queues

Instead of saying "Review completed" [this finished review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/6260263) says "This item is no longer reviewable".

Neither question nor answer have been deleted. Answer has not been edited.

"This item is no longer reviewable" mentioned [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195039/i-think-i-just-broke-review-audits) and [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261864/getting-this-item-is-not-reviewable-while-reviewing-close-vote-queue) but not the same issue.

Can you tell me what "This item is no longer reviewable" means in this context? Just curious.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The post was bumped into the queue via a Not An Answer flag. While in review, a moderator declined that flag manually. The post no longer met any criteria to be in that queue, so the review item was cancelled.