# Does deleting and undeleting a post invalidate flags and review tasks?

Tags: support, flags, low-quality-posts

In the [SO Close Vote Reviewers](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) room, the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10644914/android-expandablelistview-and-sqlite-database/34653280#34653280) was brought to our attention that, due to Not an Answer flags, made it into the [Low Quality Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/10807542):

[image: low quality review]

Strangely enough the item is no longer reviewable while only one reviewer had the chance to take action. However two users claim that their flags were helpful ([1](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/27991821#27991821) and [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8gO1l.png)). The answer is, at the time of posting, still there. We hoped however that the answer would be gone.

I'm aware of the possibility that flags (and review tasks) get reset if the OP edits their post but that seems highly unlikely in this case given the attention  it got from at least three users with enough privileges.

As the flags were all marked helpful, I don't think a moderator was involved as described in ["This item is no longer reviewable" on an ended review](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277130/this-item-is-no-longer-reviewable-on-an-ended-review).

So, is this a case of [You are flagging for moderator attention not moderator action after all](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2660/50828) or is there some system event that we are unaware of that tried to help us here?

Comment: Answer is currently deleted.

Comment: That is quick... hello meta effect...

Comment: @gnat hilariously, that title is even worse than the title here. Methinks we need a better title somewhere for searching purposes. Or a more generic canonical "Does deleting and undeleting void flags?"

Comment: @TinyGiant agree. The only way I could find it is because I vaguely recalled something about "shaken off flags". This is well searchable but hardly will be used by askers of questions about this

Comment: Yeah, it's definitely searchable, if you're @gnat. :P

Comment: **Note:** bring incidental similar cases that `fell-through-the-cracks` (using this phrase) to the [close-vote chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers), someone else will be happy to (re-)flag it for you if it is indeed NAA (as you can't flag it again for the correct reason yourself). Obviously this should *not* be used for NAA's which are declined/disputed/active!

Comment: **Update**: It has been decided on [SO Close Vote Reviewers](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) to use the tag [reflag-pls] with reason and share-link (instead of `fell-through-the-cracks` which meant the same). **Example**: `[reflag-pls] NAA - OP deleted and undeleted http://stackoverflow.com/a/#####`. Further examples: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/search?q=tagged%2Freflag-pls&room=41570  **Important**: should not be used for NAA's which are declined/disputed/active!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The post was in the [Low Quality Review Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/10807542) because of the flags on it and yes, only one person reviewed it.

This is a weird case where the user who posted the answer, deleted it when the answer was in review, which resulted in marking the outstanding flags as helpful.  The user then undeleted the answer. [Here's the link to the timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/34653280/timeline).

So those flags weren't cleared by review or a moderator, they were cleared when the user deleted the post which is by-design.

Comment: This is an interesting case to know about for sure.

Comment: This suggests the possibility that a delete / undelete is home free for further non-scrutiny of a LQ Answer (at least on those pending flags) ?

Comment: Does/Should shaking off flags this way alert the mods, or automatically reraise those flags as Community-flags? Or would that lead to too many false-positives?

Comment: @Deduplicator No, mods don't get notified when this happens.  It would _most likely be_ very noisy (No, I haven't run any numbers).