# Different wording for completed reviews

Tags: discussion, review-queues

I completed some close vote reviews today and was paging back through my history. I noticed that my completed reviews had different text:

Post 1:

> You have already reviewed this item. It needs more reviews from other users to be completed.
>
> [miken32](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1255289/miken32) reviewed this 10 minutes ago: **Close**

Post 2:

> This item is no longer reviewable.
>
> [miken32](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1255289/miken32) reviewed this 10 minutes ago: **Close**

Post 3:

> **Review completed 10 minutes ago:**
>
> [miken32](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1255289/miken32) reviewed this 10 minutes ago: **Close**

Why the different wording? They all seem to be saying the same thing.

Comment: I would guess the first one got not enough votes to be out of the queue, the second one got deleted, and the third one got enough CVs to close, or enough "leave open"to stay open?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The review is still underway.
2. The review was <s>an audit</s> invalidated. This can be because a moderator [explicitly took action](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277130/this-item-is-no-longer-reviewable-on-an-ended-review) or another action [invalidated the need for review](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165134/what-could-cause-this-item-is-no-longer-reviewable-in-the-reopen-review-queue) (can be a variety of causes)
3. The review has been completed.

Note that when it refers to the review, it's referring to that particular case, which requires multiple reviewers. So, although you may have finished your part, the review may still be in progress.

Comment: I'd figured the meaning of the first. The third threw me because I was indeed reading it as *my* review, not the review as a whole. The second is not an audit though. That says something along the lines of "audit completed 10 minutes ago."

Comment: @miken32 Can you provide a link to your second review?

Comment: Not right now, am on my phone. Will see if I can find it later though.

Comment: @miken32 again.... Maybe a deleted post? I can only see that

Comment: @Patrice That does seem like the most likely explanation.