# What are these "This item is not reviewable." audits?

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, review-audits

I've been going through the Suggested Edits queue and *frequently* when I see a review which is immediately clear as an audit, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/16512030). I'm unable to review it.

The only option that is available to me is *Next* and besides that I have the text.

> This item is not reviewable.

Is this intended?

I would understand these audits disappearing in other queues such as in [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277130/this-item-is-no-longer-reviewable-on-an-ended-review). However to the best of my knowledge the suggested edit audits are procedurally generated and so a moderator wouldn't have made the question/answer no longer fit the criteria.

<sub>*Unless they're editing my audits on the fly.*</sub>

***Edit:***

Here's more (I'll add to this list as more appear):

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/16528664
https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/16563505
https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/16563513
https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/16618345

Comment: You were the first person to receive that audit (and doesn't appear to have been reviewed by anyone else)... Something strange is going on there...

Comment: It has now been reviewed.

Comment: I'm retagging to bug as it certainly seems to be one... There's nothing obvious in the post/audit timeline that's consistent as to why they're not reviewable.

Comment: @JonClements it's worth noting that that of the suggested-edits that I've linked, they no longer all say *"This item is not reviewable."*, they may now say *"This item is no longer reviewable."* due to the time since they appeared

Comment: That last one entered the audit queue on the 29th then invalidated itself about 20 minutes later according to the post timeline... I'm guessing that might be because of trying to introduce  it into a suggested edit queue that's already reached the cap.

Comment: Almost two years ... the bug doesn't seem to have been resolved; [another occurrence](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/23378463), less than an hour ago. Could it be intentional/by design?

Comment: And still unresolved two more years later @nyedidikeke [Why can't I review a suggested edit which popped up in the review queue?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/374482/why-cant-i-review-a-suggested-edit-which-popped-up-in-the-review-queue)

Comment: And still an issue, just encountered it for the first time today. Always an edit suggested by the Community User, so clearly an audit.