# Subverting the review audit process through browser navigation?

Tags: discussion, bug

I was going through the review queue for suggested edits, when I voted to reject an edit that changed "boostrap" to "Bootstrap" thinking it was merely a capitalization issue and was not relevant. After rejecting it I decided to browse **back** to see if I missed something.

I did, it was actually correcting a typo on the word booTstrap. I then browsed **forward** and saw the review I was previously on, but for some reason it was telling me the review was "not reviewable."

I found [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261864/getting-this-item-is-not-reviewable-while-reviewing-close-vote-queue) here on meta, which suggests (albeit with one down-voted answer and no accepted ones) that this was an audit. The review 100% looked like an audit, they're rather easy to identify usually.

I decided to check to see if this was a bug, and for every review I would browse **back** and then **forward** before reviewing. This seems to break audits. Any audit that I came across was "not reviewable" after navigating back to it.

I don't know how big of an issue this is, but it seems like a relativity easy way to get around the audit system, at least for suggested edits.

Am I seeing this correctly or did I perhaps fail these 2 audits in the background and just don't realize it maybe?

Comment: Audits are meant to catch robo reviewers.  If you realize it's an audit, even if because you spend the time to see if it's an audit, then you have passed and the audit was a success.

Comment: @will Well robo-reviewers can now write a script to navigate back/forward *accept or next if its not reviewable.

Comment: I don't think robo reviewers would bother.  They don't bother paying attention, so why should they?

Comment: @Will Well that's why I wanted to ask on Meta. It seems like a small issue, but then the whole review process seems like a non-issue to me. I just assume that whomever the review process is designed to work for is probably the people who would abuse a glitch.